# belongsTo not returning results as desired

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to a `user` be able to only have one `distrito` (it means `district` in Portuguese). A `distrito`can have more than one `user`. It's a fairly simple relationship but the problem comes when you have a third table called `distritos`that it's only job is to translate numbers into strings (I don't know the name of such tables).

**Distrito table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('distrito');
```

*e.g.*

```
ID  DISTRITO
1 - Aveiro
2 - Beja
3 - ...
```

**User tables**

```
$table->string('name');
$table->string('last_name');
$table->string('profile_picture')->default('default.jpg');
$table->string('userProfile')->default('');
$table->float('stars')->default(0);
```

**distrito_user table** `this table will reference where the user live`

```
$table->integer('user_id'); //id of the user
$table->integer('distrito_id');  //Id of the district where the user lives
```

**User's model**

```
public function distritoUtilizador(){
    return $this->belongsTo(DistritoUser::class);
}
```

**DistritoUser's model**

```
protected $table = 'distrito_user';
```

**Calling the eloquent model**

```
$user = Auth::user();
dd($user->distritoUtilizador);
```

It returns `null`.

**First question:** Is this the correct way to solve my problem (the user lives somewhere and I need to fill that location)?

**If this is the right way to solve my problem:** Why it's not returning the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple one to many, just store the foreign key to distrito on the user model, no need for intermediate tables.

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('last_name');
$table->string('profile_picture')->default('default.jpg');
$table->string('userProfile')->default('');
$table->float('stars')->default(0);
$table->integer('distrito_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('distrito_id')->references('id')->on('distrito');
```

and get rid of the distrito_user table  altogether. now use has this method:

```
public function distrito(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Distrito::class, 'id');
}
```

while distrito has:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

also change distrito migration to:

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Everything is working wonders but just a quick edit to your question: `return $this->belongsTo(Distrito::class);` should be `return $this->belongsTo(Distrito::class, 'id');`. I don't know why but it's not working without the `'id'`. I'll test more in an hour but in a first glance it's working wonders. Thank you

Comment: Good too hear, did you specify a different primary key than id on the Distrito model by change?

Comment: No. My table is as the question says and the Model doesn't have any modification. Just have the `hasMany`. It's a bit weird why it's not woking without the `'id'`

Comment: That is odd, eloquent should be able to resolve the primary key based off the model name if normal conventions are followed when creating migrations and establishing model relationships. Anyhow, glad it is working for you.

Comment: It still returns null. The `return $this->belongsTo(Distrito::class, 'id');` was sometimes returning the correct value. Other times it failled to return the value.

Comment: Have you started with a fresh database since these changes? Is it possible you're looking at stale models that didn't establish relationships properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146795/discussion-between-charlie-and-btl).